# Android 11: Permission dialog is not modal anymore. Is this by design?

Tags: android-permissions

Pre Android 11, when the permission dialog comes up, you have to tap either allow or deny.  You can't tap outside the dialog box.  With Android 11, you can tap outside of the box, and if you do, it acts like a deny, which is probably not what the user expects.  Is this by design or is this a bug?  Current C# code is below.  Should this change for Android 11?

Currently, I do something like this, and in pre-Android 11, the permission dialog is modal.

```
if (permissionCheck == Permission.Denied)
   { ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { etc., etc. } 
else 
   { initialize location stuff }
```

Then my OnRequestPermissionsResult will check the result and do the right thing.

Comment: did you find a way to handle when the user clicks outside the permissions dialog? I'm facing a similar problem and a wrong code is implanted since the dismiss is taken as deny. Please let me know how you resolved this. Thanks!

Comment: Basically if they hit deny (either by saying so, or clicking outside) I just ask them again -- are you sure you want to deny.  If they say yes, then I know they meant it.  So I just put up an AlertDialog if it's a deny.